# Stripping last character from a foreach loop

Tags: php, datetime, foreach

How do I strip the last pipe out of the list of numbers that is generated?

```
$days = new DatePeriod(new DateTime, new DateInterval('P1D'), 6); 
foreach ($days as $day) { 
    echo strtoupper($day->format('d')+543); 
    echo "|";
}
```

Comment: why use `strtoupper` on number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Concat to string but add `|` before

```
$s = '';
foreach ($days as $day) { 
    if ($s) $s .= '|';
    $s .= strtoupper($day->format('d')+543); 
}
echo $s;
```

#### 2. Echo `|` only if not last item

```
$n = iterator_count($days);
foreach ($days as $i => $day) { 
    echo strtoupper($day->format('d')+543);
    if (($i+1) != $n) echo '|';
}
```

#### 3. Load to array and then implode

```
$s = array();
foreach ($days as $day) { 
    $s[] = strtoupper($day->format('d')+543); 
}
echo implode('|', $s);
```

#### 4. Concat to string then cut last `|` (or `rtrim` it)

```
$s = '';
foreach ($days as $day) { 
    $s .= strtoupper($day->format('d')+543) . '|';
}
echo substr($s, 0, -1);
# echo rtrim($s, '|');
```

Comment: boom. You nailed it. Thanks.

Comment: @portnoy-the-elder: I edited the answer, better solution now is under #1.

Answer (score 3):

collect output in the loop, and add `|` before, not after.

```
$days = new DatePeriod(new DateTime, new DateInterval('P1D'), 6); 
$echo = '';
foreach ($days as $day) { 
    if ($echo!='') $echo.='|';
    $echo.=strtoupper($day->format('d')+543); 
}
echo $echo;

570|571|572|573|544|545|546
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this as the code is written because:

1. You don't know how many iterations there will be and
2. You are directly echoing the strings (so you cannot post-process the output)

A very easy way to achieve the result you want is

```
echo implode('|', array_map(function($d) { return $d->format('d')+543; },
                            iterator_to_array($days)));
```

This works by converting the iteration of `$days` into an array, formatting the results with `array_map` and gluing them together with a standard `implode`.

Answer (score 0):

Cut last char:

```
echo substr($str,0,-1);
```

EXAMPLE

```
$days = new DatePeriod(new DateTime, new DateInterval('P1D'), 6); 
foreach ($days as $day) { 
    $str .= strtoupper($day->format('d')+543); 
    $str .= "|";
}
echo substr($str,0,-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$cnt = count($days);
$i = 0;
foreach ($days as $day) { 
    echo strtoupper($day->format('d')+543); 
        if($i++ < $cnt)
            echo "|";
 }
```

Comment: `count` doesn't work on DatePeriod object.

Answer (score -1):

You can use output buffering to control what is echo'ed.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Or the implode solution.