# How to make appear pipe according to the conditions

Tags: php, if-statement, concatenation

Here i have the variable **$json** concatenated with possible three conditions.

According the below conditions $first , $second and $third, the output should get concatenate with pipe. So that the output should be either three given below

**Expected**

---

```
first
or 
first | second
or 
first | second | third
```

---

**Here is my Code simplified :**

```
<?php
$json = "";
$first = "1";
$second = "1";
$third = "1";
$pipe = "|";
        if ($first == 1)
        {        
        $json .= "first";
        }
        $json .= $pipe;
        if ($second == 1)
        {        
        $json .= "second";
        }
        $json .= $pipe;
        if ($third == 1)
        {
        $json .= "third";
        }    
    echo $json;
?>
```

How can i make the $pipe variable to get my output expected for the variable **$json**

Note : As i use some complex flexi grid , implode still makes little complex

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://codepad.org/FDKce6Cw

Comment: I'm getting the same output as your desired output. However you should include pipe condition in your `if` condition

Comment: Your code is perfect for the desired outcome.

Comment: @Prateek @ Ancient Geek If the $second was set 0 then the output $json will be first||third, which is expected as first | third

Comment: You should include pipe condition in your if condition. http://codepad.org/CL33qXI8

Comment: Your question didn't explain what was wrong; hence, your code seemed to work. Edit the question and *explain* what is wrong, you'll get better responses.

Comment: @Prateek Then $third is set 0 the ouput will be first|second|

Comment: http://codepad.org/auib5dEN

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks, i choose implode

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stripping last character from a foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050704/stripping-last-character-from-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$json = "";
$first = "1";
$second = "1";
$third = "1";
$pipe = "|";
$data = array();
if ($first == 1)  $data[] = "first";
if ($second == 1) $data[] = "second";
if ($third == 1)  $data[] = "third";
$json = implode($pipe, $data);
echo $json;
```

Or use some other way, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19050740/67332) for example.

Comment: I didn't think of it. Nice  +1

Comment: Thanks, i should go for implode

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$array = array(
    'first'  => $first,
    'second' => $second,
    'third'  => $third
);

echo implode($pipe, array_keys(array_filter($array)));
```

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) removes any key/value pair whose value is [falsely](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) returns an array of their keys, and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) joins the values using `$pipe`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this is to always concatenate a pipe after a variable concatenation 
Then truncate the the final string by 1 character.  If you're printing straight to stdout, remove this last pipe with a back-space, space combination.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json;
$first = true;
$second = true;
$third = true;
$pipe = " | ";

if ($first === true) {
    $json .= "first";
}
if ($second === true) {
    $json .= $pipe . "second";
}
if ($third === true) {
    $json .= $pipe . "third";
}
echo $json;
```

Comment: What is the output if $first is false?

Comment: Which is expected as second | third

Comment: You'd have to have a nested if else statement within the second if statement checking the $first variable again. And if the $first variable is true concatenate the pipe at the beginning, else just concatenate the $second.